# Slide Reference vs. Link Display

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

**Problem**

Given the `beamer` class, can I label a specific slide and *same* time reference this with a custom name?

The first works with `\label<slide>[label-name]`.
The second  works with `\hypertarget{label-name}{target-text}` together with `\hyperlink{label-name}{link-text}`.
But I couldn't find a solution for both.

**Example**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\label<slide>{label-name}
Some text
\uncover<2>{target-text}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
More text
\ref[display-text]{label-name}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question. Is it something like this what you want to do?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hypertarget<1>{labelslideone}{test1}
\hypertarget<2>{labelslidetwo}{test2}
Some text
\uncover<2>{target-text}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
More text
\hyperlink{labelslideone}{go to test1}
\hyperlink{labelslidetwo}{go to test2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```